# Implementing Orientation lock

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, orientation

**Requirement :** we want to prevent rotation of device (To support only portrait mode,no landscape)

**My Implementation :** I have written a function on orientationChange event which will detect the mode (portrait or landscape) and if it is portrait mode do nothing and if it is landscape mode I am using transform rotate to rotate it back to portrait view.

**Problem with my implementation :** lets suppose portrait mode is 360px and landscape mode is 640px and my media queries are like

```
@media all and (max-width:600px){
    Selector{
         Font-size:18px;
    }
} 

@media all and (min-width:601px) and (max-width:767px){
    Selector{
         Font-size:22px;
    }
}
```

So now when in landscape mode , font-size is 22px then my function is rotating the body using transform ,so it is not same as portrait mode (font-size should be 18px in portrait mode but now it is 22px).

I don't want to write css again based on orientation .
Is it possible to rotate window object instead of body tag ??

Any better way to do this....????

Answer (score 0):

Far as i know that is not possible.
hopefully the following code will help you:

```
@media (min-width:640px) and (orientation: landscape){
    Selector{
        Font-size: 18px;
    }
}
```

Maybe this is more what you're looking for but the browser support is verry poor so maybe not a solution for you

[js Orientation lock](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/lockOrientation)

Comment: No , i have lots of code in css so writing css based on orientation is not possible